# How to debug j_security_check problems

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I am trying to set up an app to use j_security_check to login. This will run on JBoss 5 on CentOS 7. However, when I call using Postman or the login page, I always get a login error page.

I don't see any messages in server.log nor in /var/log/messsages

How can I see debug information as to what I am doing wrong?